# how can we search for a word in a firebase document field

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a social media app with Flutter Firebase. I am currently developing a hashtag feature. I want to query all the posts which contains the hashtag in its caption? ARAYCONTAINS not working

Here's my code

```js
class HashtagPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String hashtag;
  const HashtagPage({Key? key, required this.hashtag}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HashtagPage> createState() => _HashtagPageState();
}

class _HashtagPageState extends State<HashtagPage> {
  bool isExecuted = false;
  QuerySnapshot? snapshotData;

  queryData() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('all_posts')
        .where('tags', arrayContains: widget.hashtag.toLowerCase())
        .limit(500)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      snapshotData = value;
      setState(() {
        isExecuted = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    queryData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isExecuted == true ?
      mobileBody() :
    SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
        body: Center(
          child: LoadingAnimationWidget.inkDrop(
            color: Theme.of(context).indicatorColor,
            size: 40,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  mobileBody() {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: snapshotData!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
            document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return postWidget(postId: data['postId']);
          }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

A solution code written in dart for the problem

Comment: You don't. Assign words from a field to an array. Or use some other external big data query technology.

Comment: Are `.then((value) =>> ...)` value is a data you want to display or a snapshot ? I'm not a dart programmer, but I know that Firebase returns a query snapshot, not a plain array with result.

Comment: I have pasted the full code in the question. Please help.

Comment: Well, "not working" won't help anyone to solve your problem. Do you get any error?

Comment: no I'm not getting any error but It's not showing the post It means it can't find the document

Comment: Does the document have a field named "tags" with an array of tags?

Comment: yes. all the document in that collection have a field named "tags" with an array of tags

Comment: I just put .trim() after the string I was searching for and that solved it. Thank you for your help : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I wrote in a comment, the best way to do that is to have a field with "content" and array, where you filter out tags from the content field and store them as an array. You can query an array contains a string, but not a field/text contains a word.

```js
.where("tags", arrayContains: "bestfood")
```

When you assign tags to an array, make them lowercase, so there won't be any problem to search them. In `content` they can stay how PO wrote them.

Comment: great work sir.

Comment: It's not working. Here's my code

queryData() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('all_posts')
        .where('tags', arrayContains: widget.hashtag.toLowerCase())
        .limit(500)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      snapshotData = value;
      setState(() {
        isExecuted = true;
      });
    });
  }

Comment: @AbhishekRaj Edit your question and paste there code.

Comment: i've pasted the code